# Memory-efficent way to iterate over part of a large file

Tags: python, iteration, large-files

I normally avoid reading files like this:

```
with open(file) as f:
    list_of_lines = f.readlines()
```

and use this type of code instead.

```
f = open(file)
for line in file:
     #do something
```

Unless I only have to iterate over a few lines in a file (and I know which lines those are) then it think it is easier to take slices of the list_of_lines.  Now this has come back to bite me.  I have a HUGE file (reading it into memory is not possible) but I don't need to iterate over all of the lines just a few of them. I have code completed that finds where my first line is and finds how many lines after that I need to edit.  I just don't have nay idea how to write this loop.

```
n = #grep for number of lines 
start = #pattern match the start line 
f=open('big_file')
#some loop over f from start o start + n
      #edit lines
```

EDIT: my title may have lead to a debate rather than an answer.

Comment: what to you mean by "#edit lines", do something with the lines like storing them in a list or writing them to another file or modify these lines in the big file?

Comment: How are you finding the first line, and the number of lines after it you need to edit? You must be reading the file from the beginning to do that, right?

Comment: I am going to be editing the lines in the file, then printing a before and and after type thing to a separate file. I will be printing only the lines I change to the other file.

Comment: @dano I was finding that information using by using `line = subprocess.check_output("grep 'pattern' lotsoftext.txt)` I do not think that effects the answer though. The answer from @Dan that I marked below was able to help me out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem you're encountering is that storing **all** the lines of text in a list and then taking a slice uses too much memory. What you want is to read the file line-by-line, while ignoring all but a certain set of lines (say, lines `[17,34)` for example).

Try using `enumerate` to keep track of which line number you're on as you iterate through the file. Here is a generator-based approach which uses `yield` to output the interesting lines only one at a time:

```
def read_only_lines(f, start, finish):
    for ii,line in enumerate(f):
        if ii>=start and ii<finish:
            yield line
        elif ii>=finish:
            return

f = open("big text file.txt", "r")
for line in read_only_lines(f, 17, 34):
    print line
```

This `read_only_lines` function basically reimplements [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) from the standard library, so you could use that to make an even more compact implementation:

```
from itertools import islice
for line in islice(f, 17, 34):
    print line
```

If you want to capture the lines of interest in a list rather than a generator, just cast them with a list:

```
from itertools import islice
lines_of_interest = list( islice(f, 17, 34) )

do_something_awesome( lines_of_interest )
do_something_else( lines_of_interest )
```

Comment: minor issue - read_only_lines() reads the entire file, even after it has gone past finish. A break in there would be nice.

Comment: Good point, @tdelaney. Fixed it so that the generator returns at that point.

Comment: @Dan I added your answer to my code, and it is working great.  Thank you I have not encountered `enumerate()` before very useful.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Do read up on `itertools` and generator expressions; they're very powerful tool for "lazy iteration" over large data structures.

Comment: What a beauty! Thanks for this answer. One question, regarding the cases where one wants to read two different sections, thus using two islices, is there a way to do so without rewriting the loop twice? by writing twice I mean: `for line in islice(f, 17,34): out.write(line)` followed by `for line in islice(f, 50,60): out2.write(line)` Cheers

Comment: @user929304, you should check out `itertools.chain` which will allow you to concatenate the results from multiple iterators into a single iterator—could be used to combine multiple `islice`s among other things.

Comment: Thanks will do. BTW in case I have the whole file loaded in memory using read(), should I be using other ways than islice to extract parts of the file efficiently?

Comment: If you already have the file (split into lines) loaded as a `list `, there's no advantage over simply using standard list slicing.

Comment: A very common mistake that people new to python make, is assuming that an opened file will reset itself after being used like a line generator. You should probably mention that `islice(f,17,34)` and later on `islice(f,10,15)` won't work as expected unless you call `f.seek(0)` or reopen the file completely after the actual consumption of the first `islice` (generatros can be tough to comprehend).