# I can print a local variable but not return it (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, for-loop

EDIT:
Adding in

```
upperline = []
lowerline = []
```

above the `for` loop seems to allow the function to be called once as expected, but not more than once. If called a second time the following error will be thrown:

```
transitenergy = (float(upperline[1]) - float(lowerline[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If instead

```
upperline = [1,2]
lowerline = [4,5]
```

is added above the `for` loop, the function returns the expected value the first time, and then -3 every other time.

---

I am having a problem with a `for` loop seemingly being unable to retain variables when trying to return these variables, even though I can print the variables.
If I define the function as follows, when it is called , the `transitenergy` will be printed to the console, and then the following error will be thrown:

```
transitenergy = (float(upperline[1]) - float(lowerline[1]))

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'upperline' referenced before assignment"
```

```
def crossreference(datafile, lookuppointers):
    pointers = [(int(lookuppointers[0]) - 1), (int(lookuppointers[1]) - 1)]
    lowerpointer = min(pointers)
    upperpointer = max(pointers)
    for i, line in enumerate(datafile):
        if i == lowerpointer:
            lowerline = filter(lambda a: a!= '\t',filterstring(line))
        elif i == upperpointer:
            upperline = filter(lambda a: a!= '\t',filterstring(line))
            break
    transitenergy = (float(upperline[1]) - float(lowerline[1]))]
    print transitenergy
    return transitenergy
```

I have also tried moving the return statement inside the loop i.e.

```
...
elif i == upperpointer:
    upperline = filter(lambda a: a!= '\t',filterstring(line))
    transitenergy = (float(upperline[1]) - float(lowerline[1]))
    return transitenergy
```

or adding the return to a further `elif` branch i.e.

```
...
elif i == upperpointer:
    upperline = filter(lambda a: a!= '\t',filterstring(line))
elif i > upperpointer:
    transitenergy = (float(upperline[1]) - float(lowerline[1]))
    return transitenergy
```

but both of these just return a `NoneType` when the function is called and throws `TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): NoneType` when I try to call `abs()` on it (as expected of a `NoneType`).

The interesting part here, is if a print statement after defining the local `transitenergy` variable, in any of the trials I have described, calling the function prints `transitenergy` without a problem, and then throws the errors.

I should mention that the datafile used in the `datafile` argument are very large files (on the order of 100+Mb) where each line has the structure:

```
"           [line number+1]     [float]      ...."
```

(there are more numbers after this in the string but they are not relevant to the task)

The `lookuppointers` argument are lists of the following structure:

```
[int, int, ...]
```

The integers are not ordered (hence the `min` and `max`) and refer to a [line number +1] of the `datafile`

The line:

```
filter(lambda a: a!= '\t',filterstring(line))
```

Is because I am iterating over a list of many of these files, and although they usually are in the correct format, and sometimes they will have a `\t` at the beginning.

The `filterstring` function is defined as:

```
def filterstring(string):
    return filter(lambda a:a!='',string.split(" "))
```

to turn the line in the `datafile` into a list of strings.

The question is how can I return the `transitenergy` variable as it is printed.

If there is another way that I can perform this type of cross referencing without having the whole `datafile` in memory then that would work also.

Comment: `upperline` is only defined in the `elif` branch, its definition is not a given

Comment: Then why can it be printed outside of the branch?

Comment: And furthermore, to solve the problem then, should both upperline and lowerline be declared as global variables to fix this? Or rather just defined before the for loop with something like upperline = [] and lowerline = []? @MosesKoledoye

Comment: Most likely the condition `i == upperpointer` never occurs, so the assignment `upperline = ...`  never get called.

Comment: Tested this, the condition is met. If it wasn't met; how could the line `print transitenergy` print anything at all? @acw1668

Comment: Where are you calling the function? I'm suspicious the `print` works on one call, then a second call is what triggers your error.

Comment: Yes, this does infact happen, I'm calling the function within a for loop that iterates over every line of a different file that has `lookuppointers` as each line @ShadowRanger

Comment: Could you try something then: could you add upperline=[1,2] above the for loop? If it runs this way, then you probably have some line in the file that does not enter the elif branch.

Comment: What I bet is happening is you have some line or lines where the min and the max are equal, that is every number is the same and thus lowerpointer = upperpointer. In this case the elif gets skipped. Try changing the elif to if and it shouldn't get skipped.

Comment: @jfish003 Tried both of the two things you suggested; adding `upperline = [1,2]` above the for loop just moved the problem over to the `lowerline` variable and replacing the `elif` statement with an `if` statement didn't help at all unfortunately.

Comment: Ok so given that upperline =[1,2] shifted the problem to lowerline it seems to me that you have a line in your file that does not contain anything that you are looking for, so that line contains no value which attains upperpointer or lowerpointer.

Comment: @jfish003 Having gone through both files by hand, I know that this is not the case. I should also note that this function is being called many thousands of times, and the _only_ time that it works as planned is the first time; all other times it returns -3 when `upperline = [1,2]` and `lowerline = [4,5]` is added above the for loop (see my edit at the top of the question)

Comment: Ok try this then, right after the loop use print i, lowerpointer, upperpointer this way you can see what the value of i is compared to the lowerpoint and upperpointer. I would be willing to bet there is a line where no i is equal to lowerpointer and no i is equal to upper pointer

Comment: @jfish003 Oh this seems to be getting somewhere; the first call of the function gives the printout as `14592 14591 14592`, but the second printout is completely off; `29 14557 14558` does enumerate wrap around?

Comment: @jfish003, The `enumerate` only ticks up to 29 on the second call, but ticks up the whole way the first time that the it is called. Is there something that I need to refresh? Does `enumerate` save its progress or something? I should also add that calling `print max([i for i,j in enumerate(datafile)])` above the `for` loop gives `14622`, and then the `print i, lowerpointer, upperpointer` after the loop prints out `14622 14591 14592`

Comment: I am not sure enumerate is not a function I typically use, I am looking into it though

Comment: You do know that an opened file is a generator that does not automatically reset itself? I suspect you keep using the same one over and over again and therefore always starting where you left of before.

Comment: @swenzel This could be the solution; that is exactly what I am doing. The files are actually temporary files; so implementing a fix that closes them could be somewhat difficult. But I will try this next.

Comment: So let me get this straight to be absolutely sure, you want to read specific lines in the file correct?

Comment: Yup this is correct

Comment: I think that this answer will be useful then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312123/memory-efficent-way-to-iterate-over-part-of-a-large-file

Comment: Would adding datafile.seek(0) to the beginning of the function stop this from happening? @swenzel BINGO; this is our fix

Comment: Thanks guys, seems to be working as planned now.

Comment: You're welcome ;). There is plenty of room for optimization though... you could for example sort your pointers beforehand so you only need to go through the file only once. Or, since your lines have line numbers, you could do some binary search in combination with seek.

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies in in the fact that the datafile was kept open. Adding the line `datafile.seek(0)` to the function i.e.

```
def crossreference(datafile, lookuppointers):
    pointers = [(int(lookuppointers[0]) - 1), (int(lookuppointers[1]) - 1)]
    lowerpointer = min(pointers)
    upperpointer = max(pointers)
    datafile.seek(0)
    for i, line in enumerate(datafile):
        if i == lowerpointer:
            lowerline = filter(lambda a: a!= '\t',filterstring(line))
        elif i == upperpointer:
            upperline = filter(lambda a: a!= '\t',filterstring(line))
            transitenergy = (float(upperline[1]) - float(lowerline[1]))
            return transitenergy
```

Caused the file to be read from the beginning each time the function was called, as opposed to what was happening before where the file was being read from the last place it was read from.