# Does enumerate() maintain buffered file reading?

Tags: python, io, enumerate

I am needing to use an index to remember the number of line I'm on in a file to resume an operation if the program is interupted. So far I've been using this:

```py
checkpoint = 15

with open('file.dat', 'rb') as file:
    it = iter(file)
    
    for _ in range(checkpoint):
        next(it)
    
    try:
        while True:
            line = next(it)
            # do some stuff
            checkpoint += 1
    except StopIteration:
        print("EOF")
```

But this feel clunky and ineffective. I've been wondering if enumerate() applied to a file, or iterator, maintains the buffered reading property so that the file isn't loaded all at once into memory. I am also now keeping a line index for positions in the file. I've been thinking something like this:

```py
file_offset = 589

with open('file.dat', 'rb') as file:
    file.seek(file.offset)  # beginning of unprocessed line

    for idx, line in enumerate(file):
        file_offset = file.tell()
        # do stuff
```

Is this a valid approach and will enumerate work correctly here, without loading the whole into the memory?

Comment: Does it work as intended?

Comment: I'm not sure, my python process uses a lot of memory by default since I use a lot of libraries in my code, and I don't have a sufficiently large file to test it properly, hence why I asked to make sure I didn't miss anything

Comment: This sound like you want to "outsource" testing.

Comment: Once you've read the line that you want, save the value of file.tell() minus the length of the line. Subsequently you can seek to that offset to get to the same position in the file

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in [Memory-efficent way to iterate over part of a large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312123/memory-efficent-way-to-iterate-over-part-of-a-large-file), based on the answer provided, `enumerate()` creates a generator, so buffered reading of the file is maintained.

This means that `for i, line in enumerate(file)` will produce the desired result without loading the whole file into the memory.